# изменение css в зависимости от значения переменной php

Tags: php, css, mysql

Цель - добиться изменения цвета каждого блока floor, в зависимости от параметра base[6], так чтобы каждый блок был разного, если и переменная возвращает другой результат, цвета
Пробовал сделать так:

```
    <?php 
    if($base[6]=='оплачено'){ ?>
    <style type="text/css">div.floor{background-color: red} </style>
    <?php echo $base[6]; } ?>
```

Но результатом было выделение всех блоков.

```
<?php
  include_once 'connect.php';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `work`";
  $base = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $base = mysqli_fetch_all($base);
?>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>main</title>
</head>
  <div class="all_in">


      <b>Москва</b><br>
      Этаж 1<br>
           
      <?php foreach ($base as $base){ ?>
      
        <?php if($base[8] == "Москва"){?>

              <a href="main/update.php?id=<?= $base[0] ?>"><div class="floor">
              <tr> 


                <td>  <?= $base[1] ?>  <em><?= $base[7] ?>кв.м</em>  </td>


              </tr></a>
              </div> 

        <?php }else{pass;} ?>
        
      <?php } ?><br>  

</html>

<style type="text/css">

  body, html{height:100%}
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  div.head{
    height: 48px;
    width: 101%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: #3C8DBC;
  }

  div.all_in{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  div.floor{
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 20px;
  }

  tr{
    display: inline-block;
  }

  em{
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: потому что надо сделать что-то вроде `$cls = $base[6] = "..." ? "done" : ""`  а потом выводить `class = "floor <?= $cls ?>"`, и уже в `.done` настроить нужные стили